# Given a time, how can I find the time one month ago

Tags: php, date, time

Given a time, how can I find the time one month ago.

Comment: By "one month" do you mean 30 days to the second? Or would you want to adjust for a 28 or 29-day February problem?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?  For example, if it's 2:00pm December 29th, wouldn't the time one month ago be 2:00pm November 29th?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
strtotime( '-1 month', $timestamp );
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: BEWARE: This will cause unexpected results at the end of 31 day months and March. http://derickrethans.nl/obtaining-the-next-month-in-php.html

Answer (score 3):

In php you can use strtotime("-1 month").  Check out the documentation here: https://www.php.net/strtotime

Answer (score 3):

We can achieve same by using PHP's modern date handling. This will require PHP 5.2 or better.

```
// say its "2015-11-17 03:27:22"
$dtTm = new DateTime('-1 MONTH', new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles')); // first argument uses strtotime parsing
echo $dtTm->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // "2015-10-17 03:27:22"
```

Hope this adds some more info for this question.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$date = new DateTime("18-July-2008 16:30:30");
echo $date->format("d-m-Y H:i:s").'<br />';

date_sub($date, new DateInterval("P1M"));
echo '<br />'.$date->format("d-m-Y").' : 1 Month';

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP 5.2=<

```
$date = new DateTime(); // Return Datetime object for current time
$date->modify('-1 month'); // Modify to deduct a month (Also can use '+1 day', '-2 day', ..etc)
echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); // To set the format
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php

Answer (score 1):

This code is for getting 1 month before not 30 days

```
$date = "2016-03-31";

$days = date("t", strtotime($date));

echo  date("Y-m-d", strtotime( "-$days days", strtotime($date) ));
```

Answer (score 0):

These answers were driving me nuts. You can't subtract 31 days and have a sane result without skipping short months.
I'm presuming you only care about the month, not the day of the month, for a case like filtering/grouping things by year and month.

I do something like this:

`$current_ym = date('ym',strtotime("-15 days",$ts));`