# Print the time an hour ago

Tags: php, string, date, time, date-arithmetic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Given a time, how can I find the time one month ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978546/given-a-time-how-can-i-find-the-time-one-month-ago)

How can I print an hour ago in PHP using Date?

```
$date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$time(-1, now);
$result=$date.$time;
```

So If I wanted to say "John visited last "

Would print

> John visited last 20th Feb 2012, 17.26

Comment: Go ahead and do a quick google search for "php relative time function"

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 hour'));
echo 'John visited last ' . $date;
```

Answer (score 10):

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() - 3600);
```

time() -> Current timestamp

Time minus 3600 seconds, is the time 1 hour ago. To get the date formatted, you can look here for the options: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Alternatively you could use the following format:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('-1 hour'));
```

Though using that method can be a little clunky if you want to remove more specific units of time (Such as one day and 3 hours).

Thats if I've understood what you want to do correctly that is.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you would be fetching date and time from mysql and the best thing to do is using mysql's DATE_FORMAT function and work out.

Other wise in simple php you could do it like this
$date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time -3600);

Better option is to use strtotime like this one
$date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('-1 hour'));

And get the work done.

Answer (score 2):

Mmm, search the manual the function I used. You are missing something about PHP date/time functions...

```
// Get the date string for time() - 3600, that is
// the current time minus 3600 seconds (= 1 hour)
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() - 3600);

$result = $date;
```